# How to hover event on label

Tags: c++, qt, events, hover

I need a hover event on label when I move mouse over label to change a mouse pointer.
I tried something like this:

```
void MainWindow::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
if(event->GraphicsSceneHoverEnter){
    QCursor car;
    car.setShape(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    ui->label_no->setCursor(car);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only this code in MainWindow constructor.

```
QCursor crs(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
ui->label_no->setCursor(crs);
```